# try to determine the max number of character in each column

Tags: powershell

I have written a script that tries to determine the max no. of character for each column. This is what I wrote:

```
$path = 'folder path'
$file = Get-ChildItem $path\*
$FileContent = foreach ($files in $file) {
    $FileHeader = @( (Get-Content $files -First 1).Split($delimiter) )
    $importcsv = @( Import-Csv $files -Delimiter "$delimiter" )
    for ($i=0; $i -lt $FileHeader.Length; $i++) {
        #select each column
        $Column = @( $importcsv | select $FileHeader[$i] )

        #find the max no. of character
        $MaxChar = @(($Column[$i] |
                   Select -ExpandProperty $FileHeader[$i] |
                   Measure-Object -Maximum -Property Length).Maximum)

        $output = New-Object PSObject

        $output | Add-Member NoteProperty FullName ($files.FullName)
        $output | Add-Member NoteProperty FileName ($files.Name)
        $output | Add-Member NoteProperty Time (Get-Date -Format s)
        $output | Add-Member NoteProperty FileHeader ($($FileHeader[$i]))
        $output | Add-Member NoteProperty MaxCharacter ($($MaxChar[$i]))

        Write-Output $output
    }
}
```

The script above is just part of it, so `$delimiter` is already defined. And finally I will export the result as CSV.

The script runs without any error, but when I open the file it only gives me the first column/header the max no. of character, and the rest of column/header are missing.

The perfect result will be showing each column/header the max no. of character.

Is something wrong with my loop?

my boss is trying to create an automate process to finding all the information from the raw data and use those information to upload to the database, so part of the script that is missing is about determine the delimiter of the raw file, the `$CleanHeader` is clean version of `$FileHeader` (remove all special characters, turn capital letters to small letters), those cleanheaders will be use for headers in the table in the database. and he also want to know the maximum character in each column, so that info can use them in creating the size of the column in the table in the database (he knows this part can be done in sql), but he ask me whether it can be done in PowerShell or not.

Comment: Why do you need to know the maximum number of characters? And what do you mean by column? Are you asking how to find files with long names?

Comment: There's very little that can't be done in PowerShell, so the answer to a question "can XXX be done in PowerShell" is practically always "yes". The real question is: how much effort does it take to implement XXX?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$ht = @{}

# import a CSV and iterate over its rows
Import-Csv $f.FullName -Delimiter "$delimiter" | ForEach-Object {
  # iterate over the columns of each row
  $_.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
    # update the hashtable if the length of the current column value is greater
    # than the value in the hashtable
    if ($_.Value.Length -gt $ht[$_.Name]) {
      $ht[$_.Name] = $_.Value.Length
    }
  }
}

# create an object for each key in the hashtable
$date = Get-Date -Format s
$ht.Keys | ForEach-Object {
  New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
    FullName     = $f.FullName
    Name         = $f.Name
    Time         = $date
    FileHeader   = $_
    MaxCharacter = $ht[$_]
  }
}
```

Comment: I have test it and it works, I'm quite new to powershell, so I got a few beginner questions, is $_ = (Import-csv ...), is that correct? then what is $_.Name mean? I know $ht is hash table and so what is $ht[$_.Name] mean? thank you

Comment: `$_` is the current object variable (holds the current object in a pipeline). See [`about_Automatic_Variables`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

`FileHeader[$i]` was returning the column name with quotes : `"ColumnName"` instead of `ColumnName`

To fix, just add a trim to the line where you pull the header :

`$FileHeader = @( (Get-Content $files -First 1).Split($delimiter).trim('"') )`